# Overflow-x or translateX error, how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, css

Hi there is something wrong with my code when I try pressing tab  in responsive mode I  keep getting my site in overflow-x or translateX like this: [image: overflow-x oor tarnslatex]
Only when I press tab normally it doesn't.
my code is here:

```
.nav-links{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-image: url(../src/header-background-pattern.png);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%) translate3d(0,0,0);
    transition:transform 0.5s ease-in;
    padding: 5.5px;
```

}
`.nav-active {
        transform: translateX(0%);`
}

```
@keyframes navLinkFade{
from{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
}
to{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

And here is my js code:

```
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

navLinks.forEach((link,index)=>{

    if(link.style.animation){
        link.style.animation='';
    }
    else{
        link.style.animation='navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards '+(index/7+0.4)+'s';

    }
});
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: its probably translateX, that'S causing it, but you can inspect it, and see which element is causing it

Comment: @AhmedSunny I know that it's causing it but can you help me?